# Annotation pin color not changing and the detail disclosure is not coming in the Mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (MKPinAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id) annotation{

 MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];
    annView.enabled=YES;    
    [annView setCanShowCallout:NO];
    annView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    //[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationViewClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    return annView;

}
```

I m using this code only but ts not woking.....Help me!!!
Thanks in advance......

Comment: Paste the code where you are adding your annotation to the map.

Comment: i had the same, you need something like  [self.myMap addAnnotation]; as per Terente comment, if you have do show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `[annView setCanShowCallout:NO];` the call-out for the annotation cannot be displayed. And the detail disclosure will be visible in the callout.

Comment: set annView.canShowCallout = YES;